# How to configure the python Twill/Mechanize library to acces Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, browser, twill

I'm trying to run some automated functional tests using python and Twill. The tests verify that my application's OAuth login and connection endpoints work properly.

Luckily Twitter doesn't mind that Twill/Mechanize is accessing twitter.com. However, Facebook does not like the fact that I'm using Twill to access facebook.com. I get their 'Incompatible Browser' response. I simply want to access their OAuth dialog page and either allow or deny the application I'm testing. Is there a way to configure Twill/Mechanize so that Facebook will think its a standard browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try to send user agent header w/ mechanize.

Comment: I actually tried: browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')] Curious if it applies that to every request thereafter or do you have to set it before every request?

Comment: I guess it is persistent as long you reuse your browser object instance. Maybee FB does some kind of test whether browser supports javascript...?

Comment: It seems to work for me if I run the twill command `add_extra_header User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"`.  Maybe it's the lowercase "a" in your "User-agent" that made it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
from twill.commands import *

def login(email, password):
    go('http://www.facebook.com')
    add_extra_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0")
    formclear('1')
    fv("1", "email", email)
    fv("1", "pass", password)
    fv("1", "persistent", "1")
    submit()
```

and then:

```
login('something@example.com', 'password1')
```